# onActivityResul not reached

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im trying to get a value from second Activity (EditActivity) but onActivityResult is never reached. I should get the value assigned in "indice" in the main activity. This is the code:

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.listviewwithbuttons">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ListViewWithButtons">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditActivity"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Main Activity:
Here the Intent is created and sent ARRAY_ID which is effectively used in a Toast in second activity.

Here is also the onActivityResult, the Toast inside is never reached.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    String[] countries = {"Argentina", "Chile", "Brasil","Uruguay","Paraguay", "Bolivia", "Peru", "Ecuador", "Colombia", "Venezuela"};
    private static final int SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.lv_countryList);

        StringViewRender();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Elegiste: "+countries[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String index = String.valueOf(i);

                Intent cambioEditActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,EditActivity.class);
                cambioEditActivity.putExtra("ARRAY_ID", index);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(cambioEditActivity);
            }
        });
    }
    public void StringViewRender () {

        ArrayAdapter <String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,countries);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE  && resultCode  == RESULT_OK) {
                assert data != null;
                String requiredValue = data.getStringExtra("indice");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Secondary Activity:
Here is where returning Intent is created, "indice" is created and sent, and finish terminates de activity. Should trigger onActivityResult in MainActivity.

```
public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button buttonAceptar;
    EditText editTextPais;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editactivity);

        buttonAceptar = findViewById(R.id.button);
        editTextPais = findViewById(R.id.edt_pais);

        String sessionId = getIntent().getStringExtra("ARRAY_ID");

        Toast.makeText(this, sessionId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        buttonAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String respuesta = editTextPais.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("indice", respuesta);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So where are you calling `startActivityForResult`? I only see a call to `startActivity`, which doesn't return any result.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks for your response, seems that startActivityForResult is been deprecated, thats why I used startActivity alone, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Overriding `onActivityResult` is also deprecated, as per [the guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) - `registerForActivityResult` is what replaced both of those.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this. from MainActivity.class

```
            String index = String.valueOf(i);

            Intent cambioEditActivity = new 
            Intent(MainActivity.this,EditActivity.class);
            cambioEditActivity.putExtra("ARRAY_ID", index);
             startActivityForResult(cambioEditActivity, SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);


         @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE  && resultCode  == RESULT_OK) {
            assert data != null;
            String requiredValue = data.getStringExtra("indice");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

on second activity.

```
           String respuesta = editTextPais.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("indice", respuesta);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
```

this should work..

Comment: you can mark after this work